# Repeat loop does not iterate over all elements

Tags: c#

I'm using a loop of repetition in a collection of nodes, however the output and always the first input of the foreach ...

```
var all_accounts_elements = content.GetCollectionNode(
    "//div[@class='box-list-item text-c js-list-item']");

foreach (HtmlNode account_element in all_accounts_elements)
{
    //for debug only
    var copy = account_element;

    var account = new InstagramAccount();

    //for debug only
    var debug = copy.SelectSingleNode("//*[@class='title']");
    Debug.WriteLine(debug.InnerText);

    account.AccountName = account_element.SelectSingleNode("//*[@class='title']")
        .InnerText.ToTilteCase().Trim();
    account.AddedData = account_element.SelectSingleNode("//*[@class='sub']")
        .InnerText.Trim();
    account.Edit = account_element.SelectSingleNode("//*[@class='context-menu']")
        .InnerText.Trim();
    account.Message = account_element.SelectSingleNode("//*[@class='quick-info']")
        .InnerText.Trim();

    accountsList.Add(account);

}
```

Colection: [image]

1st element: [image]

2st element: [image]

Output:

```
jonisbarcelos
jonisbarcelos
```

Comment: Put a breakpoint on `accountsList.Add(account);` Perhaps there's an issue with how you are selecting the data.

Comment: Where is the code that produces the output? Where are you getting `jonisbarcelos` from? Are you looking at the `AccountName` property?

Comment: Posting a full sample of the source HTML document would help too and welcome to SO, by the way... :-)

Comment: @JuanR jonisbarcelos comes from Debug.WriteLine(debug.InnerText);

Comment: @JuanR html here https://pastebin.com/Lz4dRCjn

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your XPath selector is telling the HTMLAgilityPack to look into the entire document. Try looking at the descendants instead:

```
account.AccountName = account_element.SelectSingleNode("descendant::div[@class='title']")
    .InnerText.ToTilteCase().Trim();
account.AddedData = account_element.SelectSingleNode("descendant::div[@class='sub']")
    .InnerText.Trim();
account.Edit = account_element.SelectSingleNode("descendant::div[@class='context-menu']")
    .InnerText.Trim();
account.Message = account_element.SelectSingleNode("descendant::div[@class='quick-info']")
    .InnerText.Trim();
```

Comment: It worked perfectly thank you very much, but still I could not understand how it did not work in the usual way ... I was only getting a node and they were coming two.

Comment: The reason is that you specified a selector that looked at the entire document, so every time you ran the loop, the selector took the same first node, regardless of what child node you are calling the method in. It is not intuitive at all as one would expect the XPath expression to be applied within the context of the current node but it looks like the object keeps an internal reference to the entire document and executes against it.